# VB.NET ContextMenuStrip is not shown at actual location GDI+ control

Tags: c#, vb.net, controls, gdi+

I have a node diagram control which inherits from ContainerControl and has a list of nodes drawn in it, the nodes do not inherit from anywhere, but simply consist of a few methods and some properties.

I need to be able to right click a node and then show a ContextMenuStrip at that location. That I can do fine, but where the trouble begin is with the node diagram controls ability to scale the contents.

When the control is zoomed in our out, the ContextMenuStrip is offset. I should have taken care of this, as I'm able to correctly find out if the mouse coordinates are within the nodes bounds, but for some reason, the ContextMenuStrip does not show at the mouse coordinates.

Here's a video to showcase the problem:
https://youtu.be/QNqQnWSENN8

I'm very sorry, but I can't post most of my code because of these stupid limitations, so I'll try to provide the stuff that is connected to the problem.

So what I'm currently doing on the MouseDown event of the node diagram is:

```
Public Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim selectedNode = From n As Node In NodeContainer.Nodes Where n.Rectangle.Contains(e.Location) Select n
    If selectedNode.Count = 1 Then
        If NodeContainer.SelectedNodes.Count < 2 Then : NodeContainer.SelectNodeContainer() : End If
        NodeContainer.SelectNode(selectedNode.LastOrDefault(), False)
        NodeContainer.NodeContextMenuStrip.Show(NodeContainer, e.Location) 'Show node cms
    Else
        NodeContainer.SelectNodeContainer()
        NodeContainer.NodeContainerContextMenuStrip.Show(NodeContainer, e.Location) 'Show container cms
    End If
End Sub
```

The method is given this MouseEventArgs object:

```
Dim ev As New MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks, (e.X - AutoScrollPosition.X) / Zoom, (e.Y - AutoScrollPosition.Y) / Zoom, e.Delta)
```

That's basically how I'm doing it atm.

I have tried a couple of things:

1. Removing the NodeContainer from the show method and casting the location to screen coordinates, but that didn't work, at least not the way I did it.
2. I have tried adding the nodes location and size to e.Location, obviously didn't work either.

Hopefully you can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to give the method the original MouseEventArgs object and then make the new MouseEventArgs object in the method.

So (Line with * in front and back has either been inserted or changed):

```
Public Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(e As MouseEventArgs)
*Dim ev As New MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks, (e.X - AutoScrollPosition.X) / Zoom, (e.Y - AutoScrollPosition.Y) / Zoom, e.Delta)*

Dim selectedNode = From n As Node In NodeContainer.Nodes Where n.Rectangle.Contains(*ev.Location*) Select n
If selectedNode.Count = 1 Then
    If NodeContainer.SelectedNodes.Count < 2 Then : NodeContainer.SelectNodeContainer() : End If
    NodeContainer.SelectNode(selectedNode.LastOrDefault(), False)
    NodeContainer.NodeContextMenuStrip.Show(NodeContainer, e.Location) 'Show node cms
Else
    NodeContainer.SelectNodeContainer()
    NodeContainer.NodeContainerContextMenuStrip.Show(NodeContainer, e.Location) 'Show container cms
End If
End Sub
```